# Alternative to exit() function?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to change the class of a button if a conditon is not met (   if(strlen($username) < 5)    ) this is my code :

```
    if( strlen($username) < 5 ){
        echo '<span  class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style = "color:red"> More then 4 caracters </span>';
        $buttonClass = 'btn btn-primary disabled';
        exit();
    } 
    elseif( is_numeric($username[0]) ) {
        echo '<span  class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style = "color:red"> First character mst be a letter </span>';
        $buttonClass = 'btn btn-primary disabled';
        exit();
    }
    elseif($check < 1){
        echo '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style = "color:green"> ' . $username . ' is available</span>';
    }else{
        echo '<span  class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style = "color:red"> This username is already taken </span>';
        $buttonClass = 'btn btn-primary disabled';
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">

        var status = document.getElementById("usernamestatus");
        var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
        if(u != "") {
            hr.open("POST","register.php",true);
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                    status.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
                }
            }

</script>
```

Now i know there is something to do with the `exit()` function but if i don't put it then the html apears on the page twice,how can i stop that from happening ? Please can someone help ?

Comment: Alternative to `exit;` well, there's `return;` and `die();` is that what this question's about?

Comment: *Which* block of HTML appears twice without the `exit`?

Comment: But you are using `if/else if/else if/else`, why do you need the `exit` calls in the first place?

Comment: `return ; ` should solve the symptom. But the problem seems is a double inclusion of html file in some condition.

Comment: @Fred-ii- note that `exit` and `die` are the same thing

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML as well?

Comment: `exit;` exits your whole script so that will be the end of your output. Is this code inside a function? If so, you can use `return` to exit the function only.

Comment: @DrKey Yeah I know. That's why I left them a few options including `return`.

Comment: Oh...the HTML is outputed twice because (1) you send it to the browser when you GET the page and then add it again with `status.innerHTML`  after you make the AJAX call and POST to the same URL.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You can also throw an exception :-)

Comment: @jeroen Ah yes... the "exception" to the rule ;-)

Comment: You are probably including the HTML when you POST to it too, so you get it back as part of the response to that AJAX request you make. That's why you need the `exit`. But if you also need to change the class on that button you might want to remove the `exit` calls so that the HTML is returned in the AJAX call and replace the whole form's HTML with the returned one. I also don't think you understand the difference between client-side and server-side code: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: All the html shows up again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion is that you use the same script to handle both your initial form and the AJAX response. AJAX (which you are using in your  part) will create a seperate request and will only come as far as the exit(); (That means it *does not* again render the HTML, and therefore does not again show the  with it's new class.

Probably the easiest and cleanest way to do this is through a Status Code.

In your PHP set a header for a different status code:

```
 if(strlen($username) < 5){
      echo '<span  class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style = "color:red"> More then 4 caracters </span>';
      header('HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable');
      exit();
 }
```

In your JavaScript add another case to a successful response:

```
    if (hr.readyState == 4){
        status.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
        if (hr.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('submit').className = "btn btn-primary";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('submit').className = "btn btn-primary disabled";
        }
    }
```

Comment: the message "More then 4 caracters" is shown but the class doesn't change :(

Comment: the javascript was incorrect. The document.getElementById('submit').className = "btn btn-primary disabled" should correctly change the class. Also note you can use a browser like chrome or firefox and use the inspect to test javascript code such as this for errors.

Comment: it seems to be working,but can you tell me one more thing please ? how to "reset " the script ? for example if i modify the username and it is correct now,how can i make the button change its class again to  "btn btn-primary" ?

Comment: Well the easiest way is that if you push submit again, it will change (which it should already do, if you get a new 200 status it will give a new message).
If you want to message to disappear as soon as you start changing the username, you should add a onkeydown event to the input that sets the className back to "btn btn-primary" and the status.innerHTML = ""

Answer (score 1):

like @Rein Baarsma has already stated, the problem you are facing clearly highlights the need for proper separation of concerns.

What is happening is that, since both the form, the PHP file and the Javascript AJAX functionality are on the same page, when your request is made, the response text returns the entire page, including the form (and possibly your javascript code) resulting in the duplicate you are witnessing.

One way to avoid this issue is to separate out the various parts of your application. In this model you'd have at least two files. But this will require some re-factoring of your code, as it currently stands. See examples below:

File 1, whichi I choose to call `register-front.php` will contain your HTML and Javascript/AJAX codes:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username:</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name = "username" class="form-control" id="username" onkeyup="checkUsername()">
    <br>
    <div class = "userspan">
        <span style = "font-size:15px"id = "usernamestatus"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit" class="<?php echo $buttonClass ?>" id = "submit" >Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
function checkUsername () {
    var status = document.getElementById("usernamestatus");
    var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
    if(u != "") {
        status.innerHTML = 'Se verifica...';
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("POST","register.php",true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                var parsedReply = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                status.innerHTML = parsedReply.button;
                document.getElementById('submit').className = parsedReply.buttonClass;
            }
        }
        var v = "name="+u;
        hr.send(v);
    }
}
</script>
```

File 2, which I call `register-back.php` will contain your PHP code:

```
<?php $buttonClass = 'btn btn-primary'; ?>

<?php

$msg = "{";

if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != ""){
   $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['name']);
   $quer = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
   $resu = mysqli_query($dbc,$quer);
   $check = mysqli_num_rows($resu);
   if( strlen($username) < 5 ){
      $msg .= "'button' : '<span  class = \"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" style = \"color:red\"> More then 4 caracters </span>', 'buttonClass':'btn btn-primary disabled'";
   } 
   elseif( is_numeric($username[0]) ) {
      $msg .= "'button' : '<span  class = \"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" style = \"color:red\"> First character mst be a letter </span>', 'buttonClass':btn btn-primary disabled'";
   }
   elseif($check < 1){
      $msg .= "'button':'<span class = \"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" style = \"color:green\"> ' . $username . ' is available</span>', 'buttonClass':''";
   }else{
      $msg .= "'button': '<span  class = \"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" style = \"color:red\"> This username is already taken </span>', 'buttonClass':'btn btn-primary disabled'";
   }

   $msg .= "}";

   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   echo $msg; 
   exit;
}
?>
```